# how to get only listening ports of a process in linux

Tags: java, linux

I tried different commands `netstat` , `lsof`, but my requirement is,
I want to pass the listening port say a process x is running on chl21000303.sesson.net:**32456.**

I want a linux command which reads only the port 32456 and want to pass it in java like  java -jar runs.jar port.

So I need some commands to get only the running port or listening port. If I try netstat commands like that I am getting say some 20 lines of ports.

Comment: Including "please help" and thanks in a post is inappropriate. no distractions, no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour))

Answer (score 0):

```
netstat | awk '{print $4}' | sed -nr 's/.*:([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs java -jar runs.jar
```

I am kinda unclear about the question. The above would plug all the port numbers into the arguments of your java file

If you are sure that it will be on chl21000303.sesson.net you could instead do

```
netstat | awk '{print $4}' | sed -nr 's/chl21000303.sesson.net:([0-9]+)/\1/p' | xargs java -jar runs.jar
```

edit-

for sake of completion ill give a quick overview of what everything is doing.

netstat gets all the connections and pipes it to awk. awk gets the 4th column and pipes it to sed. sed gets the port number using a regular expression and pipes it to your java program as arguments

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will try this on monday in my project and will let you know if i have any issues. Thanks for your valuable reply and help. Now could you please explain me how this sed works and -nr and the regular expression you wrote

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in shell script

```
var=`"netstat -atn | grep LISTEN | awk {print $4}"`
for x in $var
do
    port=`echo $x | awk -F':' '{print $2}'`;
    echo $port;
done
```

You have your port number in $port you can pass it to your java script